# Propagation of Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I probably should not be attempting this, but I have gotten so far and I don't want to give up now. I want to create my own Lightbox type script. I can create an absolute div with the class ligthbox and it covers the page. Then I create a img that is fixed and it animates when loading. The I also have nav arrows to move through the photos.  All works accept when I click on the arrows it creates new close X and arrows. I don't understand because the is done through the animation function which is not attached to the arrow function.

I have added event.stopPropagation(); to the arrow function and the animate function but that did not work.

The function that initiates everything.

```
jQuery(".marks-lightbox img").click( function() {

  var Img = jQuery(this),
      cImg = Img.attr("src"),
      allImg = jQuery(".marks-lightbox img");

  //finding the current img from the available images

  for(i=0; i < allImg.length; i++) {

    if( jQuery(allImg[i]).attr("src") == Img.attr("src") ) {

      lbImgCurrent = i;

    }
  }

  makeLightBox() 

});


function makeLightBox() {

    var bodyHeight = jQuery("body").height(),
        lightbox = jQuery("<div>").addClass("lightbox").css({"width":"100vw","height":bodyHeight}),
        scrollTop = 72,
        lbContainer = jQuery("<div>").addClass("lbContainer"),
        lbImg = jQuery(".marks-lightbox img"),
        imgSRC = jQuery(lbImg[lbImgCurrent]).attr("src"),
        lbClose = jQuery("<span>").addClass("lb-close").text("X");

    jQuery("body").prepend(lightbox);

    lbContainer.appendTo(".lightbox");

    jQuery('<img src="'+ imgSRC +'">').load(function() {

      jQuery(this).appendTo(".lbContainer").css("display","none").addClass("lb-image");

      var w = jQuery(".lb-image").width(),
          h = jQuery(".lb-image").height(),
          lbw = lightbox.width(),
          margin = (lbw - w) /2;

      jQuery(this).appendTo(".lightbox").css({"position":"fixed","display":"block","width":0,"height": 0}).animate({"top":scrollTop,"width":w,"height":h,"margin-left":margin, "margin-right":margin},1000,function(event){

        var lbimg = jQuery(this),
            lbH = lbimg.height() + 63,
            lbLeft = lbimg.offset().left,
            lbW = lbimg.width(),
            larrow = jQuery("<div><</div>").addClass("left-arrow-lb lb-arrow"),
            rarrow = jQuery("<div>></div>").addClass("right-arrow-lb lb-arrow");

        larrow.appendTo("body").css({"position":"fixed","top":lbH/2,"left":lbLeft+18});

        rarrow.appendTo("body").css({"position":"fixed","top":lbH/2,"left":lbLeft+lbW-90});;

        lbClose.appendTo(".lightbox").css({"position":"fixed","top": lbH,"left": lbLeft+lbW - 18});

      });
    });
}
```

Here is the click function

```
jQuery("body").on("click",".left-arrow-lb", function() {
    console.log(jQuery(this));
    var lbImgLength = jQuery(".marks-lightbox img").length,
        lbImg = jQuery(".marks-lightbox img");

    lbImgCurrent = (lbImgCurrent < 1 ) ? lbImgLength : lbImgCurrent -1;

    var imgSRC = jQuery(lbImg[lbImgCurrent]).attr("src");
    console.log(imgSRC);
    jQuery(".lb-image").attr("src",imgSRC);

});
```

Every click creates a load new img scr and animates the photo (unexpectedly) and creates new arrows and close x.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the HTML this code is acting on

Comment: Also *I have added event.stopPropagation();* show how and where you use it

Comment: I put this in jfiddle. After putting it there I think it is because I am using .on("load"... that when a new images is being loaded jQuery runs this part of the script. Not sure how to work around this. https://jsfiddle.net/Husbandman/9frw1Lmy/57/

Comment: Every time you click an image, makeLightBox gets called.

Answer (score 0):

I found it was the on("load"... working every time an image was being loaded. So I created a var reload and set it to true. The in the on(load... function I said if not true return false. In the arrow functions set the reload to false. This prevented the on(load... working reloading.